# Preserve tabs when reading from a textarea after adding via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a problem with preserving tab characters when reading the value of a textarea. 
I'm adding the tabs as follows:

```
$("#code-editor").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 9) { // tab was pressed
        // get caret position/selection
        var start = this.selectionStart;
        var end = this.selectionEnd;

        var $this = $(this);
        var value = $this.val();

        // set textarea value to: text before caret + tab + text after caret
        $this.val(value.substring(0, start)
                    + "\t"
                    + value.substring(end));

        // put caret at right position again (add one for the tab)
        this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 1;

        // prevent the focus lose
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

The tabs are inserted correctly and are displayed in the textarea as expected.
The problem occurs when I then read the value of the textrea and try to replace to tab characters with html formatting.

```
$("#code-editor").keyup(function (e) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        //Do formatting
        var lines = value.split("\n");

        var newvalue = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            lines[i].replace(/\t/g, "<span style='padding-left:3em'></span>");
            lines[i] += "<br />";
            newvalue += lines[i];
        }

        $('#editor-displayarea').html(newvalue);
    });
```

I have discovered that the tabs do not seem to be preserved when reading from textarea.

Is there a way around this or have I taken the wrong approach?

Thanks.

Update:
I have tried using a few variations on the regular expression as stated in the comment below but to no avail.

Comment: You should escape tab in your regex i think: lines[i].replace(/\\t/g,...

Comment: I've tried that already, Ive also tried using a RegExp object like var patt=new RegExp("\t", "g"); and new RegExp("\\t", "g") but neither of them work. In chrome when I debug the javascript and read the value of  the textarea it does not show the tab characters at all but the carriage return are visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not storing the value when you replace the tabs. Try something like this (I would leave the `&nbsp;` in the span as well):

```
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var replaced = lines[i].replace(/\t/g, "<span style='padding-left:3em'>&nbsp;</span>");
    replaced += "<br />";
    newvalue += replaced;
}
```

Comment: One of the first things i tried, using plain text like the word 'tab' or just a random string but still no luck

Comment: @dekin88 I think I may have found the bug and updated my answer

Comment: Oh dear me :/ what an oversight on my part hehe. Well thanks for that mate works like a charm!

Comment: Happens to everybody. Glad to help :)